# colour not showing on browser, but shows in design view

Tags: html, css

I made a simple HTML page, made a CSS page and linked it; on Dreamweaver it shows the background is black but, when I put the browser on, it shows as white!

Code:

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css" />
 <link rel="stylesh eet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

 </body>

 </html>
```

CSS code: home.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000000; 
}
```

Comment: there isn't anything in the body, try adding some content to the page, along with changing the hex code to a **6-digit** number or a **3-digit** number

Comment: it just shows the text, but the background is still white!! on the design view it shows the background as black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a fiddle that shows what you need there

http://jsfiddle.net/85svu/

```
#000000
```

you also need to add something to the body of the page

```
<body>
  <p> here is some content</p>
</body>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION AFTER RESEARCH**

I posted a Question on [Programmers.Stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/216843/62519) And found the answer and links to be eye opening about the `<html>` and `<body>` tag CSS debate.

Here are the links

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background

http://www.sitepoint.com/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/

Comment: what would you recommend me to use other than dreamweaver for html and css

Comment: NotePad++, or just plain Notepad.  if that is all you are doing in them.  none of those IDE's display correctly, they will not show what it looks like in a browser, it will always bee different. I use the IDE's for Highlighting and indenting and things like that because it is convenient. but I never try to view my page through those IDE's they never render correctly

Comment: with notepad can i view as in design view? because i quite like dreamweaver because it has the split option so i can see what am doing, but when i open in browser it doesnt show exact. with notepad will i able to see design view n browser?

Comment: don't use Design View, use Chrome Developer Tools. along with writing the code in Notepad or notepad++. when you insert objects using design view it doesn't always give you good HTML code, it's a bad habit.  with a plain text editor you will remember more code and be able to code anywhere on any machine, even if your fun IDE isn't installed.

Answer (score 5):

Your hex color cannot have 4 digits. It needs either 3 or 6.

`#000` or `#000000`

Edit:

In case people see this answer and stop reading further and still wonder why it's white. Like everyone else said, the body will have height of zero if it has no content, so the background won't show up.

Though the odds of a body being totally empty is pretty slim..

Comment: what would you recommend me to use other than dreamweaver for html and css

Comment: This is getting off topic, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244515/what-is-the-best-text-editor-for-web-development. I use Notepad++ and Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Change `background-color` to `#000000` or `#000`.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000; 
}
```

You can abbreviate single-digit hex values like `#000000` or `#FFFFFF` or `#777777` to 3 digits for brevity (`#000`, `#FFF`, `#777` and so forth), but it will not work with any other number of digits.

Probably the reason it works in Dreamweaver but not your browser is because your body has no content, padding or margin and therefore its height is zero and you won't see any background as a result.  Temporarily add `height: 100px` or something to your `body` declaration to test the background color (or just add some content to the body).

Comment: @mali if that doesn't fix it, you probably have a style declaration of equal or higher specificity in your `css/css.css` file that is overriding the `body` declaration in `home.css`.  Post your `css.css` file and we can help out.

Comment: @mali also, add some content to the page - the markup you posted has an empty `body` which means it will have a height of `0` and therefore you won't see the background.  Add `height: 100%` to `body` and `html` temporarily for purposes of testing the background color.

Comment: what would you recommend me to use other than dreamweaver for html and css

Comment: @mali You will learn the most if you just use Notepad or any other simple text editor and your browser (I use Sublime Text).  If you want a more IDE-style editor with a preview pane, etc, I recommend Aptana Studio 3.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that no one has mentioned, changing the `html` to your black background will make it black even if there is no content.

Here is the code,

```
html {
   background: #2b2b2b;
}
```

Then you can have your background on the body as well for when you have content on your page.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5EF6c/)

Comment: is that even good coding practice to add styling to the `html` tag?

Comment: Yeah as far as I know it is. You have never done this method to add your footers background as the html background so the footer would fill to the bottom of the page? Like this, http://jsfiddle.net/LC2Tr/.

Comment: I don't believe that I have.  it would draw too much attention to the footer. besides it works the same way in the `body` tag [http://jsfiddle.net/ka69a/](http://jsfiddle.net/ka69a/)

Comment: what would you recommend me to use other than dreamweaver for html and css

Comment: @Malachi This technique is used to make the footer fill no matter how long the page content is.

Answer (score -1):

Change the background color to #000 and it will work :)

Comment: When giving answers please explain why it would work, ie the underlying cause.